# Django Rest framework not giving 403 error for unauthenticated user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-decorators

I'm making an api with django normal view using Django restframework token, decorator and permissions
like below

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def test(request, format=None):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    content = {"hello":"world"} 
    return Response(content)
```

It Always give me the result even if i didn't add a token to the header 
note that i added all the required settings
my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    #'utils',
    'schedule',

]

# SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
# 'JSON_EDITOR': True,
# }

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication', 
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
   ),
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
   ),
#     'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
#         'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
#     ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 2,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework.views.exception_handler'

}REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication', 
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
   ),
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
   ),
#     'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
#         'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
#     ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 2,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework.views.exception_handler'

}
```

> As per the documentation it should give 403 status error since user is not authenticated but it is giving 200 response with normal data

Comment: Maybe your user is session authenticated?

Comment: Hi @JahongirRahmonov but im calling the api from postman how could it be authenticated and the token is not set i  the header ?

Comment: session auth are using cookies.

Comment: How should i solve that anyone can help me please

Comment: Check that by printing `request.user.is_authenticated()` just before you return a response and let us know the result

Comment: This line is not required inside your view `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]`.

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov the result of request.user.is_authenticated() is false and the api is called normally

Comment: any help please !!!!

Comment: I found the problem The user is an anonymous user but how can i prevent anonymous users from calling the api ?